# scrollintoview is not scrolling to element (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, scrollview

I am parsing the HTML of a website and I want selenium to scroll down to all the elements containing '5 days ago'. This is the code I have:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(u"//*[contains(text(), '5 days ago')]")

for e in element:

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)


    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    if element=='5 days ago':
       break
```

It is not scrolling. Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scroll to text in element selenium webdriver python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310465/scroll-to-text-in-element-selenium-webdriver-python)

Comment: Both questions were asked by me because I had no answers so far!

Comment: Bumping or asking the same question is frowned upon. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers