# scroll to text in element selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver (chrome) to parse HTML of a website. I have this HTML:

```
<a class="_class" data-click-id="timestamp" href="https://www.reddit.com/r/" id="id" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">4 days ago</a>
```

I want selenium to scroll down to each text >4 days ago.

Is this possible?

I tried:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(u"//*[contains(text(), '4 days ago')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

but it is not working (not scrolling).

I also tried:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(u"//*[contains(text(), '4 days ago')]")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element)
```

And it is not scrolling.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

This question is the exact duplicate for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308539/scrollintoview-is-not-scrolling-to-element-python), which was also asked by me and still has no answer so far. Please help instead of reporting it a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: Both questions were asked by the same person (myslef) because there was no answer. I would appreciate if someone helps me instead of marking it as a duplicate with an unanswered question!

Comment: See @MivaScott [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308539/scrollintoview-is-not-scrolling-to-element-python#comment95453591_54308539) in your previous question.